# Adding a second group by to valuecounts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have code below as

```
df.loc[df['company'].isin(companies), 'mealtime'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
```

This gives me the value_counts for hour of day as below:

```
mealtime | value
breakfast  4242
lunch      1818
dinner     4243
latemeal   3131
```

How can I group this by on another level where if I have column called city I want expected output below:

```
city | mealtime | value
NY     breakfast   443
NY     lunch       432
NY     dinner      556
NY     latemeal    222
AL     breakfast   323
Al     lunch       555
AL     dinner      777
AL     latemeal    545
```

Where I want output above where I can also sort for largest value per city in breakfast or lunch
so if I want to see which city has largest value in breakfast or also lunch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
(df.loc[df['company'].isin(companies)]
  .groupby('city')['mealtime']
  .value_counts().reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Comment: It error with cannot insert time_of_day, already exists 

is it because I already have a column in my df called mealtime?

Comment: @Chris90 pass `name` to `reset_index`. see updated answer. Also you don't need `to_frame`.

Comment: Thxxx, also how can I then sort to see highest value for each mealtime?

Comment: but `mealtime` was the second level index. How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Thats fine I can filter for mealtime and then sort, thanks!

Comment: Ah I see you want just one for each: `output.sort_values('value').drop_duplicates('mealtime', keep='last')`.